# jQuery Plugin options

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, plugin

The user can provide a JSON object to configure the plugin when they initialise it. I want those options to be available whenever a plugin action is performed.

I have read the plugin documentation but I'd like to get confirmation that I am going about this the right way.

Plugin is initialised with:

```
$(selector).hide_and_peek("init", {options:here});
```

And individual methods may be called with:

```
$(selector).hide_and_peek("action", {options:here});
```

Here's the plugin definition:

```
(function( $ ) {

// Plugin definition.
$.fn.hide_and_peek = function(action,  options ) {

    //define plugin defaults.
    $.fn.hide_and_peek.defaults = {
        peek_offset: -10,
        peek_position: "bottom",
        default_shown: true,
        peek_show_duration:1000,
        peek_hide_duration:1000,
        center: true
    }; 

    //check to see if options are provided and extend if required.
    $.fn.hide_and_peek.custom = function(){
        if(typeof options === "undefined"){
            return $.fn.hide_and_peek.custom;
        }else{
            return $.fn.extend($.fn.hide_and_peek.custom,options);
        }
    }();

    //merge defaults and custom options
    var oOptions = $.fn.extend({}, $.fn.hide_and_peek.defaults, $.fn.hide_and_peek.custom);

    // *snip* Plugin implementation
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing (my first) jQuery plugin.

Congratulations!

> The user can provide a JSON object to configure the plugin when they initialise it.

Terminology is wrong here. JSON is the transport format that looks like a JS object, but serialized into a string. What you use is just a JS object. They look the same because JSON was modeled after the JS literal notation, which (historically) was easily "unserialized" (turned back into an object) with `eval`. Proper parsers came in later on.

```
//check to see if options are provided and extend if required.
$.fn.hide_and_peek.custom = function(){
    if(typeof options === "undefined"){
        return $.fn.hide_and_peek.custom;
    }else{
        return $.fn.extend($.fn.hide_and_peek.custom,options);
    }
}();

//merge defaults and custom options
var oOptions = $.fn.extend({}, $.fn.hide_and_peek.defaults, $.fn.hide_and_peek.custom);
```

So I assume `custom` is another level of options, maybe set during setup and globally for all instances of the plugin. You don't need to check if it's `undefined`. You can just merge it in. jQuery will take care of it being `undefined` and will just skip over it.

```
// Last will take precedence
var oOptions = $.fn.extend({}, defaults, custom, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections re terminology. 

The custom is an artifact of what I'm trying to achieve. Because its all compartmentalised i think I might have the wrong idea of whats going on regarding scoping...

I've ended up treating each call as what may be considered a "static" method in , and loading in the parameters for every call. I use custom to prevent any options that were set when the plugin was initialised being overwritten if a call is made with no options passed in.

Ultimately though im just interested in oOptions containing the correct options for any instance.

Comment: It looks like my plugin may actually be better suited as a jQueryUI plugin.

Comment: @JamesB jQueryUI plugins are just jQuery plugins :P They're just a collection of UI-related plugins actually. Internally, they're the same.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I refactored the plugin to make use of the JQ UI widget factory. This allowed me to take advantage of the stateful nature of jqui widgets.